# How to stream an endless InputStream with JAX-RS

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I have an endless `InputStream` with some data, which I want to return in response to a `GET` HTTP request. I want my web/API client to read from it endlessly. How can I do it with JAX-RS? I'm trying this:

```
@GET
@Path("/stream")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public StreamingOutput stream() {
    final InputStream input = // get it
    return new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
            while (true) {
                out.write(input.read());
                out.flush();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

But content doesn't appear for the client. However, if I add `OutputStream#close()`, the server delivers the content at that very moment. How can I make it truly streamable?

Comment: I've only used it for finite files, but perhaps you could try producing MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM

Comment: tried that, no effect :(

Comment: Which JAX-RS implementation are you using?

Comment: I'm using Jersey 1.17.1

Comment: There is a nice example now at https://dzone.com/articles/jax-rs-streaming-response

Answer (score 4):

Simply use the StreamingOutput of JAX-RS

```
@Path("/numbers")
public class NumbersResource {

    @GET
    public Response streamExample(){
        StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
            @Override
            public void write(OutputStream out) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
                Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000000 ; i++){
                    writer.write(i + " ");
                }
                writer.flush();
            }
        };
        return Response.ok(stream).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  It really helped me.  The method signature of `Response.ok(Object entity)` is so unhelpful and misleading.  It is unbelievable to me that this "modern" API from 2007 uses `Object`.  And, the Javadoc gives no hint about `StreamingOutput`.  Simply dreadful.

Answer (score 2):

So, you have flush issues, you could try to get the ServletResponse as the spec says:

> The @Context annotation can be used to indicate a dependency on a
>   Servlet-defined resource. A Servlet- based implementation MUST support
>   injection of the following Servlet-defined types: ServletConfig,
>   ServletContext, HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse.
>
> An injected HttpServletResponse allows a resource method to commit the
>   HTTP response prior to returning. An implementation MUST check the
>   committed status and only process the return value if the response is
>   not yet committed.

Then flushing everything you can, like this:

```
@Context
private HttpServletResponse context;

@GET
@Path("/stream")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String stream() {
    final InputStream input = // get it
    ServletOutputStream out = context.getOutputStream();
            while (true) {
                out.write(input.read());
                out.flush();
                context.flushBuffer();
            }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess:

```
@GET
@Path("/stream")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response stream() {
    final InputStream input = getit();
    return Response.ok(input, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE).build();        
}
```

Comment: As explained above, `InputStream` will be read entirely into memory **first**, and **then** delivered to the client. This is not what I'm looking for

Comment: Trying to use Response was a far guess, I thought it would flush this way.

Answer (score -1):

Folks should be using Java 9 or later can use `transferTo` to copy the input stream to the output stream so do this:

```java
@GET
@Path("/stream")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public StreamingOutput stream() {
    final InputStream input = // get it

        StreamingOutput stream = output -> {
            try {
                is.transferTo(output);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                throw new WebApplicationException(e);
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }
        };

        return Response.ok(stream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).build();
    }
```