# CXF buffering data when using chunked encoding

Tags: java, cxf, chunked-encoding

I've written a java REST (streaming) servlet using Apache CXF 2.5.1 and deployed it to a Tomcat 7.0.42 container. The REST endpoint is essentially an implementation of **[StreamingOutput](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html)**, wrapped it a **[Response](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html)** object that is handed off to the container when a client requests.

The nature of the service is to return a stream of sensor data to a client. This stream could theoretically be infinitely long because it's only terminated when the client disconnects. The issue arises when the data generated by the sensor comes in small quantities.

The service "works" but I'm running into an issue when it comes to the size of the data responses that the client receives. The client only receives data after an 8192 byte threshold has been broken by the service. Then the client receives 800 bytes, then 8192 bytes, then 800 bytes...

I would like the data to be sent to the client as soon as I invoke flush on the OutputStream which the container hands off to my implementation of StreamingOutput. However, the implementation of OutputStream that i'm given (WrappedOutputStream defined in org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination) has a flush method which does nothing.

Is there any way to have more control over the OutputStream that CXF uses so I can "flush" to the client on demand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately the way I was able to flush the buffer on demand was to create a CXF filter, specifically an implementation of [ResponseHandler](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/ext/ResponseHandler.html).

In the filter I grabbed the [HttpServletResponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) and the OutputStream implementation that CXF used (the one that wouldn't let me flush) from the Message implementation, wrapping them in a FilteredOutputStream. Whenever flush is invoked I explicitly invoke flush on the HttpServletResponse.

This is specific to CXF and doing it this way can create a lot more overhead, depending on how often flush is invoked, but it does allow "slow" streaming to reach the client sooner.

Please comment on any gotchas or things that I may need to be concerned about.

Comment: Nice finding !
You should create a defect and provide your patch to CXF community to see how they react.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF

Comment: Great idea.  I added another answer below with sample code that works in my setup.  I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you will want to check.  First, you will likely need to set a Content-Length header (response.setHeader()), second, you may need to set the buffer size (response.setBufferSize()).  There seems to be a discussion on this here:

[How do disable Transfer-Encoding in Tomcat 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299432/how-do-disable-transfer-encoding-in-tomcat-6)

Comment: Neither setHeader nor setBufferSize are in the contract for Response. I'm also not trying to disable chunking. How would disabling it help me? I'm pretty sure I want chunking, I just would like for CXF to use an OutputStream that respects my invocation of flush().

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure you can have chunking and also force a flush all the way through.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat itself should commit the response as soon as you perform a `flush()`. This might be a problem with CXF.

If you are up for a suggestion, I might recommend that you switch-over to using [websocket](/questions/tagged/websocket) for this kind of application: it's a much better fit for long-term streaming of data from server to client (or even vice-versa). If you don't like WebSocket, you should at least look at Servlet 3.0-spec asynchronous I/O or even Comet (though 3.0-async is a better choice IMO for support, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

This is a follow-up answer to supplement @harumph's excellent idea.  All credit belongs to this person.  I only wanted to provide a *working* example.  I am stuck on an ancient version of Apache CXF with no hope of upgrade to latest Glassfish/Jersey.  This is my "fake it until you make it". `:)`

```
public static final class FlushableHttpServletResponseOutputStream
extends OutputStream
{
    private final OutputStream delegate;
    private final HttpServletResponse response;

    public FlushableHttpServletResponseOutputStream(OutputStream delegate, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        this.delegate = ObjectArgs.checkNotNull(delegate, "delegate");
        this.response = ObjectArgs.checkNotNull(response, "response");
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b)
    throws IOException
    {
        delegate.write(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush()
    throws IOException
    {
        delegate.flush();
        // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20708446/257299
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
}

@GET  // or whatever you like
@Path("/your/url/path/here")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)  // or whatever you like
public Response
httpGetStuff(@Context HttpServletResponse response)  // auto-magically injected by CXF framework
throws Exception
{
    // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63605927/257299
    final StreamingOutput so = new StreamingOutput()
    {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream os)
        throws IOException, WebApplicationException
        {
            final FlushableHttpServletResponseOutputStream fos =
                new FlushableHttpServletResponseOutputStream(os, response);

            // Do something complex with 'fos' here.
            // Call 'fos.flush()' to immediately send all buffered data via HTTP response chunk.
            // Alternatively: You may call response.flush() directly.
        }
    };
    final Response x = Response.ok(so).build();
    return x;
}
```

For careful readers, you can find exactly where Apache CXF ignores a flush request here: `org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.WrappedOutputStream.flush()` (version 2.2.12):

```
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        //ignore until we close 
        // or we'll force chunking and cause all kinds of network packets
    }
```